# Time Difference Between Two Javascript Dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, jsx

I cant get my time difference between two dates to work out for a countdown timer. I have been following a number of different online sources but it's still not working. daysDiff is not displaying on screen. This is my code:

```
const currentDate = (new Date).toUTCString();
const futureDate = new Date(2028, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0);
const diff = futureDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
const daysDiff = diff / (1000 & 60 * 60 * 24);

const render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            React.createElement('pre', null, daysDiff.toString()),
        ),
        document.getElementById('CarbonClock'),
    );
}

setInterval(render, 1000);
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You are assiging your `currentDate` to a string. As such you lose all methods related to the `Date` class on `currentDate` since it is *not* an instantiation of it.

Comment: Other than some really obvious syntax errors declaring a JS Date object, this isn't how you create a React component and render it. I suggest you start with some of the react tutorials in the [Getting Started](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) section. Typos: `currentDate` should just be `new Date()` and your `daysDiff` calculation should be `diff / 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` to be as of today, around 2,680 days.

Comment: Thanks folks. It's working now. I literally just started learning react, I've only watched 3 hours of tutorials so a longgggg way to go! Appreciate the advice. If you want to post it as an answer I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

- `currentDate` needs to be a JS Date object in order to invoke `getTime` on it.
- Typo in diff calculation, it should be `diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)`

## Sample Solution

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const computeDiff = () => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const futureDate = new Date(2028, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0);
    const diff = futureDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
    return diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  };
  const [daysDiff, setDaysDiff] = useState(computeDiff());

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      setDaysDiff(computeDiff());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, []);


  return <pre>{daysDiff.toString()}</pre>;
}
```

- `computeDiff` is a function with factored logic to compute and return the days diff.
- `useEffect` hook is to start the update interval to update local component state with the days diff (to rerender) and returns a clean up function to clear the interval when the component unmounts.

[image: Edit time-difference-between-two-javascript-dates]

Comment: I have Babel converting the above to js in my dist folder from jsx, and my cshtml file is calling the script <script src="~/dist/CountCO2Clock.js"></script>. But it is not rendering on my page. I don't see anywhere in your code where you are specifying that the component should be rendered inside the correct HTML component on the page, in my original code this was done with document.getElementById('CarbonClock') ? So I'm sure your code is working...but nothing is showing on my page...

Comment: @DMur It is common to have an index.js file that imports the app container and renders it into a DOM element where the DOM element is declared in the index.html file in the public directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Date javascript native object or you can use moment. I would suggest using moment if you are doing a lot of date manipulation. This is just another option since Date option was already provided

You can get the difference in many formats but here is a quick example to use in your code from the resource provided

```
 const future= moment([2028, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0]);
 const current = moment();
 const diffDays = future.diff(current, 'days');
```

Here is an example providing all types of ways to initialize the moment object and create the diff.

```
   moment(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array)
     .diff(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array);
```

Resource:

https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/

Comment: Thanks I tried moment as one of my attempts before coming to stack overflow, using both the nuget package and npm, but I couldn't get it working. No doubt due to some error on my part rather than the moment package.

Comment: @DMur I’ve updated the answer with exactly how you would get moment working with your example. Good luck!